# Why is function shmget (key_t , size_t , int ) returning -1 in Netbeans but it runs normally when compiled on the terminal?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* to allow use of function: atoi() */
#include "process.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int  main(int  argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    size_t size;
    int ShmID;
    int *ShmPTR;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if (argc != 5) 
    {
        printf("Use: %s #1 #2 #3 #4\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    ShmID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    if (ShmID < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        printf("*** shmget error (server) ***\n");
        printf("\nPrint: %d",ShmID);
        printf("\nPrint: %d",errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s","\nsuccess\n");
        printf("\n%d\n", ShmID);

    }

    return NOERRORS;
}
```

Output in NetBeans:

> shmget: Function not implemented
>   *** shmget error (server) ***
>
> Print: -1
>
> Print: 88
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 94ms)

When I compile the code at the terminal through putty, it functions properly and `shmget()` doesn't return `-1`. The `perror()` message in Netbeans says "function not implemented." What is causing this? I just reinstalled the C compiler, Make, GDB, and C++ compiler as well, but no fix.

Comment: Are you using the exact same compiler and compiler arguments in and outside of Netbeans?

Comment: Same arguments, but  the compiler at my university must be different since it works when I SSH through putty and connect to their server. I followed the official Net-beans instructions for installing the gcc:https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Comment: Do you mean that you're running Netbeans on a different computer than the one you're compiling manually on?

Comment: You are probably running this under windows, where you need to start the `cygserver` or similar

Comment: Windows doesn't have shared memory and shared semaphores. I don't know if `cygwin` or similar products provide emulated shared memory.

Comment: @alvits cygserver should emulate that

Comment: Yes I'm using Netbeans in windows. How would I go about using cygserver in netbeans? Is that possible?!

Comment: Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my problem. Here are some steps that can hopefully be easily followed:

1. Install these 4 packages from Cygwin Setup:

libxcb-shm-devel: X Protoco C-Language Bindings (shm development)

libxcb-shm0: X Protoco C-Language Bindings (shm runtime)

cygrunsrv: NT/W2k service initiator

cygrunsrv-debuginfo: Debug info for cygrunsrv

2. Run this command in the NetBeans terminal. Simply copy and paste it there:

/usr/bin/cygserver-config

3. Follow the instructions which ask you to enter yes and it should work.